# How to generate java classes annotated with jacksonxml annotations from XML file

Tags: java, jackson

I know how to generate JAXB classes from XSD schema file. But I am trying to find a way to generate the Jackson XML annotated java POJOs from XML/XSD?

Please refer below code for expected:

XML:

```
<person>
        <name>xyz<name>
    </person>
```

POJO:

```
public class Person {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Anybody got the answers?

Comment: I did not find any solution. I had to add the annotations manually!